# mysql query does not return expected result

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mysql tables.

table-1: table-item:

---

```
id  | itemid | itemname | catid
---------------------------------
1   |   1    |  Pen     |  1
2   |   2    |  Pencil  |  1
3   |   3    | Sharpner |  1
4   |   4    |  Book    |  2
5   |   5    |  Khata   |  2
6   |   6    |  Bag     |  3 
7   |   7    |  File    |  3  
---------------------------------
```

table-2: yearly-item:

---

```
id  | itemid |catid| year
-----------------------------
1   |   1    |  1  | 2015
2   |   3    |  1  | 2015
3   |   4    |  2  | 2015
4   |   6    |  3  | 2015
5   |   1    |  2  | 2016
6   |   1    |  1  | 2016  
------------------------------
```

I want to get a list of items of `catid-1` from `table-item` for the year-2016 which is not present in `yearly-item` table.

---

```
id  | itemid | itemname | catid
---------------------------------
2   |   2    |  Pencil  |  1
3   |   3    | Sharpner |  1
---------------------------------
```

for that purpose, while executing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_item t LEFT JOIN yearly_item y ON t.itemid=y.itemid AND t.catid=y.catid WHERE t.catid=1 AND y.year='2016' AND y.itemid IS NULL
```

it is giving this result:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Comment: why don't you try removing this part `AND y.itemid IS NULL`

Comment: @mega6382, Correct. This is meaningless. I think the OP tried something like `NOT NULL`

Comment: If I ommit `NOT NULL`, It will return which items are present in `yearly-item` for the year 2016. But I want the reverse. I want which items are not present in `yearly-item` table for 2016 but present in `table_item` table for same `catid`

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid whay don't you try `y.year!='2016'`

Comment: @mega6382, It will return items present in `yearly-item` for the year 2015

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select b.itemid, b.itemname, b.catid, a.year 
from yearly_item a, item b
where year = 2016
and b.itemid != a.itemid
and b.catid = 1
and a.catid = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfd66/14/0